# Hide one report print based on condition odoo 11

Tags: xml, report, odoo-11

I want to show my report it based on some condition. More clearly

```
   attrs="{'invisible': [('type','=','3')]}"/>


<report
    id="print_res"
    string="Print Result"
    model="result.manager"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="result_manager.result.manager_print_result"
    file="result_manager.result.manager_print_result"
    attrs="{'invisible': [('type','=','3')]}"/>
```

Hide this in picture if field type (selection) = 3

[image]

Comment: You can do overall by JS edition, if you want to hide this for specific portion then you need to inherit JS and try by including your model name there.

Comment: thank you @KevalMehta for your information, is you a small example of code js some model to hide the button ''Print"

Answer (score 0):

No way to get it done in Odoo without some js customizations on some framework widgets to get this working.

Comment: thank you @AxelMendoza for your information, is you a small example of code js some model to hide the button ''Print"